# How i version firebase code without credentials?

Tags: firebase

When you sign up to firebase they tell you to place this snippet in your code:

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
      apiKey: "your api key",
      authDomain: "domain",
      databaseURL: "database url",
      storageBucket: "storage bucket",
      messagingSenderId: "messaging sender id"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Turns out i want to version it publicly on Github. Is there a way i can use some kind of environment variable or should i just don't version a **credentials.js** script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information in that snippet is meant to be publicly shared with the users of your web app.

These are not secrets or credentials, but they're identifiers that allow the app code to find the Firebase project on Google's servers.

That said: many teams do not want to check it in to version control system, but instead force each developer to use their own Firebase project for development/testing.

Comment: thanks Frank, appreciate the help. Firebase as default allow localhost access to the cloud collections. Therefore if sharing it on Github means everyone will be able to mess with production data from their local machines. And there's no way to disable that "allow localhost" configuration. Then I'll stick with what you said about keeping it out of the VCS.

Comment: You will need to distribute these keys to all users of your app. Security on Firebase is not through hostname/IP filtering, nor through "not knowing the secret". Instead if is based on [asking your users to sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and then [securing your database with security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).